# c++ Library for trajectory correction

Tags: quadcopter

I have a trajectory of a quadcopter in 3D. Out of all the poses in the trajectory, I want to correct one of the poses. I then want to adapt the rest of the poses based on the newly corrected pose. I understand that this is a common problem in robotics and there would be a number of solutions. I want a tried and tested c++ library that does this as I want to integrate this feature in my system but not spend time on building it myself. What are the possible c++ libraries I can use?

Comment: How do you get the trajectory? Is your trajectory generator taking into account the physics of the system ? Is you new pose feasible ?

Comment: Trajectory is obtained using a stereo camera by tracking features. So I have the location and orientation of the camera for every point in the trajectory. The corrected trajectory point comes from another source. It is also just the pose information. All I have is a chain of poses.

Comment: So you manually fly and record the trajectory and then 'correct' on point ?

Comment: Yes, I fly manually and I get the trajectory information real time. I just want to correct the pose for one of those trajectory points.

Comment: But you want to refly the corrected trajectory ?

Comment: Corrected trajectory is just for visualization. I just want to show that I am able to correct the trajectory using an external source. I don't want to refly the trajectory.

Comment: Ok, and I guess that the 'correction' is significantly fare away from the other points, right ?

Comment: Yes it is far from the other points. What I was thinking is that, once correction is done to a point is would reshape the entire trajectory (optimal trajectory passing through that point).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ceres-solver](http://ceres-solver.org/) library which is nonlinear optimization framework implemented for problems like pose optimization and/or bundle adjustment. It supports ICP , bundle adjustment , pose graph optimization and other techniques which is relative to your problem. I think you should glance at it first.

Comment: I found that ceres-solver has an example implementation called pose_graph_3d  that does a optimization of the 3D trajectory. I got it working with sample .g2o datasets. It uses the g2o format for representing trajectory. The format captures poses of each node (VERTEX_SE3) and relative orientation between the nodes (EDGE_SE3). But how is the relative orientation usually found? All I have is a chain of poses (only vertices)  How do you think I can estimate the relative poses of each node in my problem? I also have a node for which I know the corrected pose. How does that affect other nodes?

Comment: As far as i understand you are building keyframe based map. I think one solution could be distributing the drift /error among the keyframes.